# How to copy info from one excel to a template excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am working with Excel and I have to export some columns to another one but this second one is a template having some colors, the logo of a company and stuff.
Is there any way to preserve the look and functionality that `template.xlsx` has?

**My code:**

```py
import pandas as pd

#variables for source file, worksheets, and empty dictionary for dataframes
spreadsheet_file = pd.ExcelFile('example.xlsx')
worksheets = spreadsheet_file.sheet_names

appended_data = {}
cat_dic = {"Part Number":"CÓDIGO", "QTY":"QT", "Description":"DESCRIÇÃO", "Material":"MATERIAL", "Company":"MARCA","Category":"OPERAÇÃO"}
d = {}

for sheet_name in worksheets:
  df = pd.read_excel(spreadsheet_file, sheet_name)
  #Getting only the columns asked: "Part Number","QTY","Description","Material","Company","Category"
  df = df[["Part Number","QTY","Description","Material","Company","Category"]]
  #Organizing info:
  #1º By Category
  #2º By Description
  df = df.sort_values(['Category', 'Description'], ascending = [False, False])
  appended_data = df.to_dict()
  #Change Key names
  d = dict((cat_dic[key], value) for (key, value) in appended_data.items())
  #Exporting Data
  df2 = pd.DataFrame(d)
  df2.to_excel('template2.xlsx',sheet_name='Projeto',index=False)
```

**Example:**

[image]

**Template:**

[image]

**My output:**

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use openpyxl if you want to only update the text and keep the format, color, etc. as-is in the template. Updated code below. Note that

- I have not taken your df2 code as the template file already has the new headers. Only updating the data from each worksheet into the file
- You can read each worksheet using read_excel, but writing will need to be using the openpyxl.load_workbook and finally saving the file once all worksheets are read
- Open the template file shown in pic above using load_workbook before the FOR loop and save to a new file template2 after the FOR loop is complete

```
spreadsheet_file = pd.ExcelFile('example.xlsx')
worksheets = spreadsheet_file.sheet_names
#cat_dic = {"Part Number":"CÓDIGO", "QTY":"QT", "Description":"DESCRIÇÃO", "Material":"MATERIAL", "Company":"MARCA","Category":"OPERAÇÃO"}
#d = {}

import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Template.xlsx')  ##Your Template file
ws=wb['Sheet1']
rownumber=2 ##Skip 2 rows and start writing from row 3 - first two are headers in template file

for sheet_name in worksheets:
    df = pd.read_excel(spreadsheet_file, sheet_name)
    #Getting only the columns asked: "Part Number","QTY","Description","Material","Company","Category"
    df = df[["Part Number","QTY","Description","Material","Company","Category"]]
    #Organizing info:
    #1º By Category
    #2º By Description
    df = df.sort_values(['Category', 'Description'], ascending = [False, False])

    rows = dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=False) ## Read all rows from df, but don't read index or header
    for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
        for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
             ws.cell(row=r_idx+rownumber, column=c_idx, value=value) Write to cell, but after rownumber + row index
            
    rownumber += len(df) ##Move the rownumber to end, so next worksheet data comes after this sheet's data 

wb.save('template2.xlsx')
```

Comment: It shouldn't be only `ws.cell(row = r_idx+1, ...)` instead of the `ws.cell(row=r_idx+rownumber,...)`? What's the purpose of `rownumber+ len(df)` .

Comment: First part - it is `ws.cell(row=r_idx+rownumber,....)` in the code. Second part - as you have multiple worksheets you are reading and writing into one single file and worksheet, each time you finish reading a particular worksheet of say 10 rows, and move to the next worksheet, you need to add 10 to rownumber so that you start writing from the (10+2)th row. Basically moving the pointer where you write to down so that you don't overwrite when reading the next worksheet... What is the issue you are facing? Is something not working?

Comment: Sorry I had it badly idented, it works perfectly fine. It isn't nothing to worry the logo is missing but the data and the rest is ok. Ty for the explanation and everything.